# How to Remove TopMost element From ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have an Arraylist In Which I want to remove the single top element from Arraylist(i.e. POP in Stack),I have used .Remove() method, But it doesn't work,So How can i remove only single element from arraylist

For example-If arraytlist contains 96,97,98,99,100 When used .RemoveAt(0) Its going to remove the element 96,I want to remove the item 100 From arraylist ,So how can i remove this top item?

Comment: `ArrayList.RemoveAt(0)`?

Comment: Please show how you tried to use that Remove method. Edit your question to include that code.

Comment: @Aron when compared to a stack that would be the bottom most element not the top most. However it's unclear from the post what is actually meant with top most aside from the implicit comparison to a stack where that element added the latest would be the top most, that is (generally) the last element of a list not the first

Comment: @RuneFS I got confused when the OP said the "top" of the array. What I really don't get is why he isn't using a stack.

Comment: Are you using any loop for inserting your array values @user1659510?

Comment: No any loop used..just tried answer of @ColinE

Comment: can you please see my new edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
ArrayList list = …

// remove the last item
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.removeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
ar.Add("Delete");
ar.Add("The");
ar.Add("Top element");

ArrayList.RemoveAt(0);
```

> Removes the element at the specified index of the ArrayList.

Also to quote the **remarks**:

> In collections of contiguous elements, such as lists, the elements
>   that follow the removed element move up to occupy the vacated spot. If
>   the collection is indexed, the indexes of the elements that are moved
>   are also updated. This behavior does not apply to collections where
>   elements are conceptually grouped into buckets, such as a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

First you find the array length using below code

```
int length = yourarray.Length;
```

next put this length in removeat

```
yourarray.RemoveAt(length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 4 };
int numToRemove = 1;
int numIdx = Array.IndexOf(numbers, numToRemove);
List<int> tmp = new List<int>(numbers);
tmp.RemoveAt(numIdx);
numbers = tmp.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
....
myAL.RemoveAt(myAL.Count - 1);
```